# Instantiating a Type Parameter Without Passing an Object

Tags: java, oop, type-parameter

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299998/instantiating-object-of-type-parameter) question. I want to be able to instantiate an object of the type parameter type, but also without needing to pass in a "factory". I really need to be contained all in the one class.

```
public class myClass<E> {
    E someObject;

    public myClass(){
         someObject = new E();
    }
}
```

Previous solutions required the constructor of myClass to be changed to have a factory parameter, and then to call the constructor of that, but for my purposes I don't want to modify any calls to myClass from the outside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you don't know what `E` is, nor how to construct it. It could be any type (it's [universally quantified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification)). You need to supply evidence that, whatever `E` is, it can really be constructed. A "factory" of a given type serves as a kind of witness to the fact that it can.

Think about this for a second: What if I pass `Void` as the parameter `E`? How would you go about constructing a value of type Void?

Being able to construct `E` *for all `E`* would be like creating something out of nothing. It's a logical impossibility. `∀E. E` is an uninhabited set.

What you really want is either for `E` to have a bound, or to pass a constructor (factory) as a witness of the fact that `E` is in the set of constructable objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, as explained in answers to the linked question, you can't do that. Modify the interface to pass in a factory object. (NB: `Class` makes a bad factory.)

Answer (score 0):

You know your code doesn't work, and you are expecting a solution with a close enough syntax.

How about this?

```
//doesn't work. cannot make x.someObject a new String()
//MyClass<String> x = new MyClass<String>();

//this can work...
MyClass<String> x = MyClass.neu(String.class);

public class MyClass<E>
{
    static public <T> MyClass<T> neu(Class<T> clazz){...}
}
```