# how to create in best way an instance from the class object

Tags: java, class, object, instance, processing

There is a way to avoid the slow reflection to create an instance from a class, obviously within another method ? For example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.create(Dog.class, "rocky");

class Foo {
    Object create(Class object, String dogName) {
        //create an instance of the class 'object' here passing the argument to constructor
        //e.g. Object obj = new object(dogName); <-- this is wrong

        return obj;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
   Dog(String dogName) {
       this.name = dogName;
   }
}

class Animal {
    String name;
}
```

I cannot create the instance using the keyword "new", because I must create the instance in another method in a dynamic way...

You have carte blanche to improve in the best way (like performance) this code :) Thank you!

Comment: Well, the obvious choice is a `switch` statement to select from among the possible `new SomeClass()` invocations.  Next would be to use ClassLoader.loadClass to get a Class pointer, then Class.newInstance().  After that are the reflections options.

Comment: The "switch" no because the result it should be as dynamic as well (for the final user).. I'm looking for other solutions like hot licks suggests, thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave your Dog and Animal classes the same. and use the Builder pattern

```
  public interface Builder<T> {
  public T build(String nameString);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
  Builder<Dog> builder =  new Builder<Dog>()
  {

     @Override
     public Dog build(String nameString)
     {
        return new Dog(nameString);
     }

  };
 Dog dog = builder.build("Rocky");
 System.out.print(dog.name);
```

}

The answers over at [Instantiating object of type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299998/instantiating-object-of-type-parameter) explain it further as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T> T create(Class<T> myClass, String constructorArg) 
throws IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
    Constructor<T> toCall = myClass.getConstructor(String.class);
    return toCall.newInstance(constructorArg);
}
```

Comment: error: "Found too many characters { without a } to match it." at the row of the "throws" keyword

Comment: Sorry, I added the `throws` clause at the wrong place.  I've fixed it now.

Comment: O.O Now "error noSuchMethodException" at row of the "[...] myClass.getConstructor( [..]" :O

Comment: So do you have a constructor, in the class that you're using, that takes only a `String` as an argument?  That message says otherwise.

Comment: I have replaced with .getConstructor(float.class, float.class) because the constructor requires two floats arguments but still raises the same error

Comment: So you wrote `myClass.getConstructor(float.class,float.class)` and then `toCall.newInstance(float1, float2)` or something of that kind?

Comment: yes, see the code here if you want :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495012/strange-error-in-java-reflection-processing

Comment: It looks from that example like `Dog` is a non-static inner class of something else.  You never told us that.  If that's the case, you need to pass a reference to an object of the outer class as the first argument of `newInstance`; and the type of it as the first argument to `getConstructor`.