# strange error in java reflection (processing)

Tags: java, class, reflection, processing

From an answer in this my previous question: [how to create in best way an instance from the class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494183/how-to-create-in-best-way-an-instance-from-the-class-object/22494236)

I'm trying to do what he suggests but I don't know how to fix the error.

**Code:**

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Foo {
   public <T> T create(float x, float y, Class<T> myClass) 
   throws Exception {
      Constructor<T> toCall = myClass.getConstructor(float.class, float.class);
      return toCall.newInstance(x, y);
  }
}

class Dog {
   public Dog(float x, float y) {
      print(x);
      print(y);
   } 
}

Foo foo = new Foo();

try {
   foo.create(10.0f, 10.0f, Dog.class);
 } catch (Exception e) {
   print(e);
}
```

**Exception:**

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sketch_140319d$1Dog.<init>(float, float)`

Comment: Do something like `for(Constructor<?> c : Dog.class.getDeclaredConstructors()) print(c);` (or however you print a line in processing) and tell us what it says.

Comment: result: public sketch_140319e$1Dog(sketch_140319e,float,float)

Comment: The answer by @DavidWallace is correct then. Dog is an inner class. You need to either pass it a `sketch_140319e` instance or declare it as static (if processing lets you do either of those things).

Comment: Yeah! I have found this: http://www.processing.org/reference/environment/ Specifically in the "advanced" section of the sketch guide. It's possibile to write "straight java code" renaming the sketch suffix.. only renaming with .java this code works perfectly printing 10.0 thank you so much radiodef and david wallace :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have just commented on your other question, this won't work if `Dog` is a non-static inner class of `sketch_140319`, which the error message suggests.  I guess you stripped out the `sketch_140319` class from your question - I don't know why you did that, when this is what the problem was.

You need to *either* make `Dog` static, *or* add `sketch_140319.class` as the first argument to `getConstructor` and an instance of `sketch_140319` as the first argument to `newInstance`.

Answer (score 2):

you can't call

```
foo.create(10.0, 10.0, Dog.class);
```

because 10.0 is a double, not a float

to call it like a float, do

```
foo.create(10.0f, 10.0f, Dog.class);
```

**Update**: my code is

```
class Dog {
    public Dog(float x, float y) {
        print(x);
        print(y);
    }

    private void print(float x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

class Foo {
   public <T> T create(float x, float y, Class<T> myClass) 
   throws Exception {
      Constructor<T> toCall = myClass.getConstructor(float.class, float.class);
      return toCall.newInstance(x, y);
  }
}
```

and

```
public class SomeOtherClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        try {
           foo.create(10.0f, 10.0f, Dog.class);
         } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and it returned

```
10.0
10.0
```

Comment: hmm replaced with 10.0f, same exception... :(

Comment: try defining each class in a separate file. For me, this way, it worked

Comment: np. just my 2c, keep the classes apart, each one in one file.