# Create object from Class instance

Tags: java, class

I want to create objects from different classes extending the same class. Can you explain how it will work. Examples would be nice.

Thank you.

```
class MainClass{

   private <T extends DataPoint> void someMethod(Class<T> clazz) {
      new clazz(2,3);//<-- create object of class (did not work)
   }

   private void anotherClass(){
      someMethod(GreenDataPoint.class);
      someMethod(BlueDataPoint.class);
   }
}

class DataPoint {
   int x;
   int y;
   DataPoint(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}

class BlueDataPoint extends DataPoint {BlueDataPoint(int x, int y){super(x,y);...}}

class GreenDataPoint extends DataPoint {GreenDataPoint (int x, int y){super(x,y);...}
```

Comment: A closer duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to create an instance of a dynamically selected class. Obtain a constructor with [`getConstructor()`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) and [invoke it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) with the necessary arguments. The `Class` object has a `newInstance()` method which is almost the same, but using a `Constructor` will report any errors in a manner more consistent with other reflective methods.

```
Constructor<T> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
T point = ctor.newInstance(2, 3);
```

Comment: Constructor must be public of course...  Thank you very much!

Comment: @JanneckLange You can grant yourself access to the constructor if necessary: [`setAccessible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-) Of course, if there's a security manager installed and you don't have the necessary permissions, this attempt to escalate access will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`new clazz();`

try

`clazz.newInstance();`

Good luck

Comment: no compiler errors anymore, thank you. I changed my question. How can i create a new instance with parameters?

Comment: I really don't know where you would use this but...
clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[] {Integer.class, Integer.class}).newInstance(2,3);

Comment: This works aswell when changing Integer.class to Integer.TYPE